# LWC: How to access clientHeight from within a component

Tags: lightning-web-components, document

I currently have `document.documentElement.clientHeight` in one of my LWC components. However looking at the latest [release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_lwc_dom_api.htm) for Winter '20 it seems like this way of accessing the `clientHeight` will be deprecated soon.

What would be the correct way of accessing the `clientHeight` if I am not going off of the `document` object?

**EDIT** To give you a little bit more context, I am using the `clientHeight` as a way to accurately calculate the position of my component which has a `display: fixed`.

Comment: Wrap it in an aura component with a lockerservice level low enough to access this value. Why they do this to us, I really don't know though.

Comment: Yeah, it's getting really complicated! Thanks for this, I will have to try it out. I still hope to get a better answer to this.

Comment: Looking at those notes, all you have to do is expose the client height via an @api attribute and read that. You could even broadcast a heightChanged custom event

Comment: A component can get it's own height and I think it can get the window height, so I think you'll be ok.